# C++ comparison and decreasing variables

Tags: c++, variables, comparison

```
 if(y-- > 0 && matriz[x][y--]!=9 && matriz[x][y--]!=0)
```

When i'm doing this, my variable **y** is not decremented, right? And i can do this comparison **y-- > 0**?

Imagine that i have y=0, i want to compare if -1 > 0.

Thanks

Comment: of course its decremented, use `y - 1` if you don't want it to be decremented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Assuming all tests pass*, your code is effectively equivalent to this:

```
if (y > 0)
{
    y--; // post-decrement

    if (matriz[x][y] != 9)
    {
        y--; // post-decrement

        if (matriz[x][y] != 0)
        {
            y--; // post-decrement

            // all true
        }
    }
}
```

If any fail, you still decrement (equivalence would be in an else-clause), but I'm omitting that for brevity.

Hopefully this is enough to clarify. I find it quite unwieldy, and if `y < 2` at the start you'll end up with a negative index, which is probably a bad thing.

Comment: The problem is that some people think that being clever is being a good programmer. Please folks write code that YOU are able to come back to in a years time and can figure out what is going on in an hour.

Comment: 'Clever' is a bad word 'round these parts.

Comment: Yes, that clarified me! And now I see that what I wrote was not what I wanted

Comment: Your code is not equivalent. Consider starting condition `y==0`.

Comment: Actually for any y<=0, y will not get decremented.

Comment: But i got the idea of GMan! Thanks 

What i really wanted was something like :


 `if(y-1 > 0 && matriz[x][y-1]!=9 && matriz[x][y-1]!=0)`

Comment: @Rob: Oh right, thanks. I was implicitly assuming they all passed, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If `y=0`, your final two conditions will not be evaluated, since the first condition will fail.

If you want your first comparison to be `-1>0`, you need a prefix decrement: `--y > 0`

Comment: Thanks, it is what i want, but now can you explain me the differences between y-- and --y?

Comment: y-- is the postfix increment operator, it will increment the value y after the comparison takes place. --y is the prefix increment operator, it will increment y beforehand. If this helped you, please vote on the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do the comparison. Why are you writing such code? Please Please write could that is readable and that is understandable.